# Understainding Rails queries in loops

Tags: mysql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I could use some help understanding Rails queries in loops.

Loop 1:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :005 > (1..3).each do |i|
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :006 >     Unit.find(i)
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :007?>   end
  Unit Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `units`.* FROM `units` WHERE `units`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
  Unit Load (0.1ms)  SELECT `units`.* FROM `units` WHERE `units`.`id` = 2 LIMIT 1
  Unit Load (0.1ms)  SELECT `units`.* FROM `units` WHERE `units`.`id` = 3 LIMIT 1
 => 1..3
```

---

Loop 2:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :008 > (1..3).each do |i|
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :009 >     Unit.where("id = ?", i)
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :010?>   end
 => 1..3
```

---

Loop 3:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :011 > (1..3).each do |i|
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :012 >     Unit.find(i)
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :013?>   end
  Unit Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `units`.* FROM `units` WHERE `units`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
  Unit Load (0.1ms)  SELECT `units`.* FROM `units` WHERE `units`.`id` = 2 LIMIT 1
  Unit Load (0.1ms)  SELECT `units`.* FROM `units` WHERE `units`.`id` = 3 LIMIT 1
 => 1..3
```

Why didn't the second loop run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Unit.where("id = ?", i)` doesn't actually run a query, it just sets up an `ActiveRecord::Relation`. So on it's own, it just evaluates to an expression. To actually run the query, you would do this:

```
Unit.where("id = ?", i).first
```

Comment: But if I ran `Unit.where("id = ?", i)` individually without any loop, it will work. Does this means in loops, I need to put something like `.first`?

Comment: If you run it individually it shouldn't. Can you should exactly what you did to make it run by itself?

Comment: Did you mean show? Does this info documented anywhere? Or is this general knowledge?

Comment: "The methods are: where select group order reorder reverse_order limit offset joins includes lock readonly from having. All of the above methods return an instance of ActiveRecord::Relation."